# how to re-start a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, android-runonuithread

I have two threads, one of them starts when i press a button. it just display values from 1-20 on the button `btn.settext(""+ j)`. inside the listener fo that button I wrote the following:

```
btn_listener.setOnClickLstener(new Listener) {
    public void onClickListener(view v) {
        if (!t2.isAlive()) {
            t2.start()
        }
    }
}
```

t2 is a thread. what happens at run time is, when I click the button while the thread2 is running nothing happens, but, when the thread2 finishes it job and i ckick the button the app crashes. any reason why that happens?

Comment: You can't restart a thread.

Comment: do u mean once a thread did its runnable job it will be dead, or something like that. sorry for the lack of understanding

Comment: Yes, you can't restart a thread but you can stop thread and start another one(the same like first one)

Comment: From JavaDoc:It is never legal to start a thread more than once.
In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed
execution.

Comment: yeah once its run method finishes, you can't restart it. You can however reinitialize the thread then start it. So just reinitialize the thread then start it.Problem fix.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm

Comment: @j4rey89 well, "reinitializing" a thread is creating a new instance.

Comment: @j4rey89 just making it clear for other readers, because the wording may be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

A thread cannot be restarted.

According to [SCJP by Kathy Sierra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060):

After you called the `start()` method on a thread, it cannot be restarted; it runs until completion, then it dissolves, and is considered dead (although you can still call its specific methods on it, you cannot call start() again).

If you call `start()` a second time, it will cause an exception (an `IllegalThreadStateException`,
which is a `RuntimeException`).

Comment: whos SCJP by Kathy Sierra?

Comment: @rmaik: Kathy Sierra is famous book author